# Confluent KSQL server on Windows - could not find or load main class

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-10, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'd like to connect to my own Kafka instance in order to try KSQL. I downloaded the latest version of Confluent Open Source platform - https://www.confluent.io/download/

I follow the https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/index.html and try to start KSQL server on my Windows 10 machine from Git Bash:

```
ksql-server-start ksql-server.properties
```

but it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServe                                                                                                                                                                                               rMain
```

What am I doing wrong and how to properly start it?

Comment: Have you tried using the CMD or PowerShell?

Comment: I have added `confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.0.0`  and now able to connect to this server via another CLI image. Please see my updated answer

Comment: If you have answered your question, please put it below instead of updating the question. Also, Docker is only a workaround to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.0.0` Docker image(below is Maven io.fabric8 docker-maven-plugin code):

```
<image>
    <name>confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.0.0</name>
    <alias>cp-ksql-server</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>8088:8088</port>
        </ports>
        <links>
            <link>kafka:kafka</link>
        </links>
        <env>
            <KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS>${local.ip}:9092</KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS>
            <KSQL_LISTENERS>http://0.0.0.0:8088/</KSQL_LISTENERS>
            <KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID>confluent_test_2</KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID>
        </env>
    </run>
</image>
```

and now able to connect to KSQL CLI via following CLI image:

```
docker run -it confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli http://172.22.160.1:8088
```